# GET http://localhost:3000/dashboard/js/appclient.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js

I know there are a lot of questions this kind but I can't figure out why `dashboard.html` can't find `appclient.js`, but `index.html` can find `appclient.js`. 
I'm getting the error: `GET http://localhost:3000/dashboard/js/appclient.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

app.js

```
// /login redirects the client to /dashboard/:uid if correctly authenticated
app.route("/login")
.get((req,res) => {
     res.sendFile('./public/index.html', {root: __dirname})
 })

app.route("/dashboard/:uid")
    .get((req,res) => {
        res.sendFile('./public/dashboard.html', {root: __dirname})
     })
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<script type="module" src="js/appclient.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
     <myapp>
       <h1> {{ title }} </h1>
    </myapp>
</body>
</html>
```

dashboard.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="module" src="js/appclient.js" defer></script>
    <title>Dash</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>dash</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

appclient.js

```
import Vue from './lib/vue.esm.browser.js'
import VueResource from './lib/vue-resource.esm.js'
Vue.use(VueResource); 

const myApp = new Vue({
    name: "myapp",
    el: ' myapp',
    data: {  // 
        title: "Hello World!", 
    }
})
```

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFulH.png)

Comment: Dashboard.html is looking up the .js at http://localhost:3000/dashboard/js/. Thats also and endpoint of your dashboard route. Please consider reading the documentations of express, vue etc. A bit more. You are using none of the parts of your app as intented...

Answer (score 0):

You're using a route relative to the current URL which in this case might not work. I'm assuming your are exposing the 'public' directory using `express.static`. The `js` files should be accessible as a absolute route, `/js/appclient.js`.

```
<script type="module" src="/js/appclient.js" defer></script>
```